# work with CI and ZEND class

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I work with CodeIgniter 2.2
and I place all zend files in codeigniter and I can use all zend classes
tutorial explained hier http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/02/21/using-zend-framework-with-codeigniter/ AND it works!

but when I call your class it gives me class Zend_Willy_Wordpress don't exist. So I think it is path issue or one think I don't get and that is where the developer on http://www.binpress.com/app/wordpress-xmlrpc-to-zend-framework-connector/562 say:

```
autoloadernamespaces.Wally = "Wally_"
<?php 
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,  array(
     realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src'),
     get_include_path(),
)));

//Zend autoloader
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$autoloader->registerNamespace("Wally_");
$autoloader->registerNamespace("Zend_");
```

O yes in CI I call it like this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('zend');
$CI->zend->load('Zend/Wally/Wordpress');
$wp = new Zend_Wally_Wordpress("http://pathtosite/xmlrpc.php", "admin", "pass");
```

and hie ris error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Wally_Wordpress' not found in /home/public/application/controllers/wordpres.php on line 32
```

But I don't have aplication.ini becsuse I develop on CI....
Maybe you have no wxpirience with CI, but MAybe you have some tips

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but have you set your PHP Include Path to include application\libraries ?

Two options:

**Option 1:** In your php.ini add the full path to your CI application\libraries folder

**Option 2:** Modify the CI index.php file to include this folder. Refer Step 3 mentioned in http://www.gotphp.com/codeigniter-with-zend-framework-libraries/54312/